# How to generate key token on Azure portal?

Tags: azure, manageiq

I try to monitor Azure with ManageIQ. The ManageIQ cloud provider requests the Azure client id and Azure client token. But I have no idea how to find client id and to generate key token on Azure portal. How can I find them?

Comment: I am not familar with ManageIQ, but if you want to get Azure AD Application clientId and  secret  key on Azure portal to generate key token, you could refer to this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-azure-active-directory-application).

Comment: Yes, some places refer to `Application ID` as the `client ID`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sign in to **Azure Portal** and select your default directory (if you have multiple directories).

**Azure Active Directory** => **App registrations** => **+ New application registration** (Name: demo Application Type: Web app/ API, Sign-on URL: http://demo.com) => **Create**

[image]

Go to **App registrations** => Select your **Application** => **Settings** => **API Access** => **Keys** => (Keyname, Duration) => **Save**

**Note:** *Copy the key value. You won’t able to retrieve after you leave this blade.*

[image]

Finally, here is your **Application ID (Client ID)** and **Keys (Client Key)**:

[image]